# How Kafka Orderering Services creates the block?

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric

I need a detail answer for this Kafka Orderering Services,
- Which Orderer node creates the block amoung the other orderers.

Comment: First of tell us what you have understood and what are your understandings. Then asking the question is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at this design document of Hyperledger Fabric Team.

This explains how it works and how they come up with this design.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/19JihmW-8blTzN99lAubOfseLUZqdrB6sBR0HsRgCAnY/edit